# ploting multiple lines but not all shown in diagram

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

i have something weird going on. I am trying to plot several lines, it shows all plots in the legend, but one line is missing. how can that be?
I am reading a file that contains my data, that works!

This is my code:

```
f = open(wk_dir+"/Total_Evaluation.txt","r+")
with open(wk_dir+"/Total_Evaluation.txt","r+") as f1:
    data10 = f1.read()
    data11=data10.replace(","," ")
    TESTDATA = StringIO(data11)
df_eval = pd.read_table(TESTDATA, sep=" ")
df_eval.columns = ["alternativesFound", "alternativesOne","alternativesPenalty","trajectory_amount","resolution","map_name","runtimeAlgo","runtimePathlet","runtimePrePro","runtimeDijkstra","dijkstraLength","runtimeIntersection","runtimeHomotopy","runtimeRTree"]
#ALTERNATIVES FOUND/TRAJEKTORY INPUT EVALUATION
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x=[]
y1=[]
y2=[]
y3=[]
y4=[]
y5=[]
for i, g in df_eval.groupby('trajectory_amount'):
    foundAlt=df_eval["alternativesFound"].mean()
    y1.append(foundAlt)
    foundMax=df_eval["alternativesFound"].max()
    y2.append(foundMax)
    foundMin=df_eval["alternativesFound"].min()
    y3.append(foundMin)
    foundOne=df_eval["alternativesOne"].mean()
    y4.append(foundOne)
    foundPen=df_eval["alternativesPenalty"].mean()
    y5.append(foundPen)
    x.append(i)
df=pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y1': y1, 'y2': y2, 'y3': y3, 'y4': y4, 'y5': y5 })
plt.plot( 'x', 'y1',data=df, marker='o',label="Durchschnittlich gefundene Routen")
plt.plot( 'x', 'y2',data=df, marker='o',label="Minimum gefundener Routen")
plt.plot( 'x', 'y3',data=df, marker='o',label="Maximum gefundener Routen")
plt.plot( 'x', 'y4',data=df, marker='o',label="Durchschnittilch gefundene Routen One-Patching")
plt.plot( 'x', 'y5',data=df, marker='o',label="Durchschnittilch gefundene Routen Penalty")
plt.title("Verhaeltnis von gefundenen alternativen Routen und Groesse des Trajektorieninputs")
plt.legend()
plt.savefig("Alterantives_TrajectoryInput_Evaluation.png")
```

Here an example of a plot that just shows 4 instead of 5 lines (red one is missing):
[image]

does anyone know how that can be? I am plotting several figures this way, so right after this piece of code i have just the same lines just with different variable names

Comment: why do you open file twice and also first time with unsafe open method(as expected - you forget to close it later)?

Comment: Is the red line overwritten by one of the other lines as they have the same coordinates?

Comment: Can you make your example minimalistic?

Comment: You don't use `g` anywhere in your loop, hence you will always get the same value in your resulting lists. The missing curve is not really missing; it's just composed of the exact same values as the last one; this means that `df_eval["alternativesOne"].mean()` is exactly equal to `df_eval["alternativesPenalty"].mean()`. If that is unexpected, you need to find out yourself why that is the case, since the data used here is unknown.